# Can't load 3ds Model with multiple texture files using Rajawali for android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rajawali

I am loading a 3ds model using Rajawali for android and its displaying correctly.

```
    parser = new Loader3DSMax(this, R.raw.riale_3ds);
```

But the object has multiple Texture jpgs provided with it. I cant figure out how to use those Textures together in Rajawali. I have seen the object opens correctly in other 3d model viewers on my PC.

```
        material.addTexture(new Texture("dcmap1", R.drawable.dcmap1));
        material.addTexture(new Texture("dcmap2", R.drawable.dcmap2));
        material.addTexture(new Texture("dcmap3", R.drawable.dcmap3));
```

I am applying this material on the object, if I apply only one it seems ok but when I do something as above it messes up.

Comment: Does Rajawali permit the use of multiple textures in a material?

Comment: The textures are blending, but I need to map them on specific coordinates. This should be possible with Rajawali

Comment: Otherwise where and how can I combine to create one texture file